# Custom json in Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have configured in an Spring 3 application a ContentNegotiatingViewResolver so when I invoke a controller with a URL which looks like **.json it returns a json object using jackson library.

If I call this method:

```
@RequestMapping("/myURL.json")
public List<MyClass> myMethod(){
    List<MyClass> mylist = myService.getList();
    return mylist;
}
```

In the JSON I receive I have:

```
{"myClassList":[
   { object 1 in json },
   { object 2 in json },
   { object 3 in json } ...
 ]
}
```

my questions are: ¿is there any way to configure the name myClassList which is used in the json? ¿is it possible in this way a json without this variable (something like the following one)?

```
[
   { object 1 in json },
   { object 2 in json },
   { object 3 in json } ...
]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return a org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView object, instead of a List object directly. On the modelAndView object you can set the name of the key. Please refer to the following snippet:

```
@RequestMapping("/myURL.json")
public ModelAndView myMethod(){
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    List<MyClass> mylist = myService.getList();
    modelAndView.addObject("MyClassName", myList);
    return modelAndView;
}
```